# VLC python binding doesn't work in mac osx

Tags: python, macos, vlc

Whenever I try to open a mp4 file in a python interface using the vlc.py file, I get these errors:

```
TagLib: MP4: No audio tracks
[000000010091beb8] core video output error: video output creation failed
[00000001010274b8] core decoder error: failed to create video output
[000000010091beb8] core video output error: video output creation failed
[00000001010274b8] core decoder error: failed to create video output
```

This question helps a little but I'm still confused and didn't get it to work. 
[vlc mac python binding no video output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308384/vlc-mac-python-binding-no-video-output)

The interface works and opens up videos in windows, but not osx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For VLC**

Save the parameters as they should be. Close VLC and reopen it. Don't open the parameters again but just try the following command in a console (considering you use the 4222 port in the configuration of VLC):

> telnet localhost 4222

**For .plist**

It seems that the path /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4 you provide as your path to python is wrong, as it should be the path to the python executable file (usually called python). Is there a python file in this path? If so, adds /python at the end. You could also be sure of that path using the which python command if it works on Mac. I'm not myself a Mac user, some some nice other users of TraktForVLC gave me in #7 the information to provide a way for Mac users to automatize the execution.

**For TraktForVLC**

If the previous step doesn't help, you should also be able to verify if TraktForVLC works properly using the debug mode:

> ./TraktForVLC.py --debug --small-timers

And then looking at the generated TraktForVLC-DEBUG.log file that should be in the logs/ directory. You could then provide that file!